# sparkSQL function cast(right()),cast(left()) support pyspark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

Hello i have the sql query and want to execute it using spark but not sure what is the exact problem here is my query,

here are some sample files

```
 '2_CALL_2700_MMP345768_PLL_20160401_104150' => logfile6

 '2_CALL_2700_MMP345768_RTT_20160401_103931' ==> logfile5



aa = sqlcontext.sql("SELECT cast(right(Logfile6,6) as time) as 'log6_time',cast(right(Logfile5,6) as time) as 'log5_time',right(left(timediff(cast(right(Logfile6,6) as time),cast(right(Logfile5,6) as time)),5),2)*60 + right(timediff(cast(right(Logfile6,6) as time),cast(right(Logfile5,6) as time)),2) as 'MT(sec)' from qq1 where timestamp > '2016-04-01 00:00:00'")
```

While executing in spark throwing error,

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.sql.
```

: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.18] failure: ``as'' expected but `(' found

```
SELECT cast(right(Logfile6,6) as time) as 'log6_time',cast(right(Logfile5,6) as time) as 'log5_time',right(left(timediff(cast(right(Logfile6,6) as time),cast(right(Logfile5,6) as time)),5),2)*60 + right(timediff(cast(right(Logfile6,6) as time),cast(right(Logfile5,6) as time)),2) as 'MT(sec)' from qq1 where timestamp > '2016-04-01 00:00:00' 
             ^
```

And the same query will return result in mysql,

```
'10:41:50', '10:39:31', '139'
```

OR is there any best way to achieve this, for calculating time duration.